# How to show all annotations at once in Preview?

Tags: preview

I just got an heavily commented pdf, when I open it in Preview, all annotations (highlights, notes) are "hidden", i.e. do not show up in the left margin. I can display them by clicking on them but I would like to see them all at once without having to click on each of them individually. I couldn't find a menu item but maybe I missed it? Or is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: What version of OS X do you have? 10.8 only seems to display highlights and anchored notes in the sidebar.

Comment: I have 10.7.4 and so Preview 5.5.2

Comment: Has anyone found a way to do this in 10.8+ yet?

Comment: In newer versions of Preview, you can review *all annotations* by opening the inspector (`cmd-I`) and selecting the annotations tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a workaround, as I couldn't find a hotkey or menu option to do this. Still, clicking

```
View > Hide Notes
```

and then

```
View > Show Notes
```

Will show all anotations. I can now see all the annotations without manually clicking them. This worked on Preview 5.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Click *View* or *View Menu* icon in the upper left, then *Highlight* and *Notes*.

Answer (score 1):

For Preview 8.1, I was also concerned that all my Notes were minimized (their term, not "hidden").
Solution is to change the default (new since 10.7 I think):

> View > Highlights and Notes

Once this is toggled, the Notes again show in margins.

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct shortcut for it now. ***Cmd + alt + 4***

**Other shortcuts:**

- See table of contents: Cmd + alt + 3
- See thumbnails: Cmd + alt + 2